# Networking with Graylog in Qemu?

Tags: networking, logs, virtual-machine, network-interface, qemu

I want to run Graylog inside a qemu VM, then send it logs and access its web interface from the host OS. First I created a Debian Jessie VM and installed Graylog using their [official guide](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/installation/os/debian.html), then I created another VM using their pre-packaged [virtual appliance](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/installation/virtual_machine_appliances.html) after converting it to qcow2. These are the commands used to start either VM:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ~/debian.img -boot c -m 4096 -enable-kvm -smp 2 -cpu kvm64 -net nic,vlan=0,model=virtio -net user

qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ~/graylog-2.1.2-1.qcow2 -boot c -m 4096 -enable-kvm -smp 2 -cpu kvm64 -net nic,vlan=0,model=virtio -net user
```

I have been unable to communicate with either VM from my host, which is connected to the network via DHCP. Using ifconfig shows that both VMs believe their eth0 IP to be 10.0.2.15. The VMs are able to use commands like curl, wget and apt, but contacting them from my host OS produces no response.

Do I need to adjust my qemu commands to use a different network interface? Do I need to modify my VMs somehow?

---

EDIT: Using curl I was able to get the VM's public IP, which leads to the network firewall. Do I need to add an exception to my firewall?